# Convert Stream to String in Java

Tags: java, string, dictionary, stream, java-stream

I want to convert a Stream of a Map<> into a String, to append it to a textArea. I tried some methods, the last with StringBuilder, but they don't work.

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> String sortByAscendentValue(Map<K, V> map, int maxSize) {

    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> sorted =
            map.entrySet().stream()
               .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) sorted));
    String read;

    try {
        while ((read=br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(read);
            sBuilder.append(read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sorted.limit(maxSize).forEach(System.out::println);

    return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample map, along with what the string output should be?

Comment: I think you're getting confused here between Java's two (confusingly-named) different types of 'stream'. You should be able achieve your objective much more simply, without all the `BufferedReader` stuff, if you just look at [`Collectors.joining()`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-join-and-split).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can collect the entries into a single `String` as follows:

```
  String sorted =
        map.entrySet().stream()
           .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
           .map(e-> e.getKey().toString() + "=" + e.getValue().toString())
           .collect(Collectors.joining (","));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider slight change to *@Eran*'s code, with regard to the fact that `HashMap.Entry.toString()` already does joining by `=` for you:

```
String sorted =
    map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .map(Objects::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: I would recommend against this  .The API documentation for [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) (which is what `entrySet` is defined to return a `Set` of) does not specify the format for `toString`.  Since it is not a documented part of the API, different or future versions of Java could deviate from this format without breaking the API contract.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do this, you can use the Steams API to do this. First, you map each entry in the map to a single string - the concatenated string of key and value. Once you have that, you can simply use the `reduce()` method or `collect()` method to do it.

Code snippet using 'reduce()' method will look something like this:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("sam1", "sam1");
    map.put("sam2", "sam2");

    String concatString = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(element-> element.getKey().toString() + " : " + element.getValue().toString())
        .reduce("", (str1,str2) -> str1 + " , " + str2).substring(3);

    System.out.println(concatString);
```

This will give you the following output:

```
sam2 : sam2 , sam1 : sam1
```

You can also use the `collect()' method instead of`reduce()` method. It will look something like this:

```
    String concatString = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(element-> element.getKey().toString() + " : " + element.getValue().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.reducing("", (str1,str2) -> str1 + " , " + str2)).substring(3);
```

Both methods give the same output.